# How to programmatically click a tab in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am using a glasspane on the top of my application. However I want the JTabbedPane to be clickable. I know how to do it with JButton by adding a mouse listener on the glasspane and then use this method [getDeepestComponentAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getDeepestComponentAt%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int%29)  from SwingUtilities. However when I do the same for JTabbedPane I am able to retrieve the JTabbedPane instance with this method, but I want to select the tab that the user clicked. I can't use the `setSelectedIndex(..)` (at least not directly) since I only have a point on the content pane. Anyone who knows how to allow for tab selection?

This  is basically how I do it with the button: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html (look at  the example for glasspane).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried JTabbedPane's `indexAtLocation(int, int)`?